# How make nuitka compile faster?

Tags: python-3.x, nuitka

I use `nuitka` compile my python code, but compile time is very slow, can anyone have good idea to solve this?

```
Nuitka-Progress:INFO: Doing module dependency considerations for 'codecs':
Nuitka-Progress:INFO: Optimizing module 'abc', 0 more modules to go after that.
Nuitka-Progress:INFO: Doing module dependency considerations for 'abc':
Nuitka:INFO: Completed Python level compilation and optimization.
Nuitka:INFO: Generating source code for C backend compiler.
Nuitka:INFO: Total memory usage before generating C code: 1.16 GB (1245917184 bytes):
Nuitka:INFO: Total memory usage before running scons: 1.16 GB (1249931264 bytes):
Nuitka:INFO: Running data composer tool for optimal constant value handling.
Nuitka:INFO: Running C compilation via Scons.
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Backend C compiler: gcc (gcc).
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Backend linking program (no progress information available).
```

Comment: What do you mean really slow? How much time does it take? Also, incidentally, what makes you think you could speed that up? Compilation is a long process, much longer than simply interpreting a program.

Comment: @BlackBeans I want it compile in 5 minutes, but sometime it may cost 30 minutes.

Comment: You know, compiling stuff can take time. There are projects for which the whole compilation can take hours. It's, a *priori*, no clear at all compiling it could take only 5 mintes.

Answer (score 0):

It's nearly impossible, you can try puttin `--standalone` instead of `--onefile` option to disable onefile stuffing up, which takes some extra time. But then you end up with a folder, whatever you do with it.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that 30 minutes is a reasonable compile time for your program and you may not be able to go faster, but here are some ideas to try:

1. Remove unnecessary code like test loops or outdated (or never fully implemented) features
2. Remove unnecessary packages and modules
3. If you are using a large package like numpy to do one little thing, try to find a way to do what you need to do without the large package
4. If you see any anti-bloat warnings, see instructions here to remove unwanted modules:
   https://nuitka.net/info/unwanted-module.html
5. Read about --nofollow-import-to in the manual. This can remove unnecessary code by specifying exactly what should be excluded.
   https://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html